# Does Java Socket cache DNS?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, dns, nio

The ctor for Socket has versions that take the server as either a string or InetAddress. Are the results of the DNS lookup cached, so that another constructed Socket will skip performing the lookup and use the cached value, if available? And if so, does this apply to both versions, or just the one taking an InetAddress?

Comment: Yes. DNS lookups are cached by the resolver.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Java documentation only talks about caching under InetAddress, saying the class has a cache (I'm assuming that means it's shared between all objects of the class). But what about when one uses the Socket ctor that takes a string instead of InetAddress? Can one assume that there's an internal InetAddress that also shares in that cache?

Comment: @DisplayName That constructor uses `InetAddress` to resolve the name. It's the same cache.

Comment: That's because DNS name resolution is done by `gethostbyname2()` (which is native code, it's the same resolution process of every program on your system - so it's a system level cache).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't follow. That's a GNU extension, and it doesn't maintain a cache. Java does that.

Comment: @EJP Fair enough. I'm looking on linux. I don't really know how much it varies in other implementations and platforms.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's still there in 1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Java Socket cache DNS?

No, but `InetAddress` does, or something under its hood, and `Socket` uses `InetAddress` to resolve names, so in effect yes.

See the [Java Networking Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html), `networkaddress.cache.ttl` and friends.